# When do you discard in Crazy pineapple?

Tags: rules, pineapple

I have seen conflicting information on when to discard your third hole card when playing crazy pineapple. One source says after the betting after the flop and one says after the River card is exposed.
Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Pineapple and crazy pineapple are two versions of pineapple. I believe in regular pineapple the disarding is preflop, in the crazy version it is done post flop.